# Expectation and the equal in distribution

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory

Is the following statement true?

If $X$ and $Y$ are 2 random variables and $\text{ }$$f$ is any bounded function then $\mathbb{E}(f(X))=\mathbb{E}(f(Y))$ if and only if $X$ and $Y$ have equal distribution?

Are there some counterexamples of this statement?

Answer (score 1):

If $P_X=P_Y$, then clearly the expectations are equal. For the opposite direction, let $f(x):=1_{A}(x)$, where $A\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. Then
$$
P_X(A)=\mathsf{E}f(X)=\mathsf{E}f(Y)=P_Y(A).
$$